# Ansible Filter multiple entries from stdout after matching the condition

Tags: ansible

I am trying to get pool name, free and Total space of each storage pool. Below is stdout of a command module with each pool detail in it. I am storing the command output in a var pools. I could not work this out with debug. Can anyone help how can I do this? I need to debug (pool_name), (free_capacity_gb) and (total_capacity_gb) of each pool from below output. My ansible knowledge is average. I am using ansible 2.6 on RHEL 7. Thanks

I have not used loop_control before but trying to use as per example found in google. Not sure what is wrong in it.

Playbook code:

```
 ---
 - hosts: localhost
   tasks:

   - name: Get Pools List
     shell: cinder get-pools --detail
     register: pools
   - debug:
       msg: "{{ item.total_capacity_gb }} - {{ item.free_capacity_gb }} - {{ item.pool_name }}"
     with_items: "{{ pools }}"
     loop_control:
       label: "loop control output : {{ item.total_capacity_gb }} | {{ item.free_capacity_gb }} | {{ item.pool_name }}"
```

## ansible-playbook pools-list.yml --syntax-check does not return any errors.

Error upon playbook run:

fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {
    "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'ansible.utils.unsafe_proxy.AnsibleUnsafeText object' has no attribute 'total_capacity_gb'\n\nThe error appears to have been in '/home/user/pools-list.yml': line 8, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n    register: pools\n  - debug:\n    ^ here\n"
}

## This is the output of command module used in above playbook without debug:

```
 ---------------------------+------------------------------------------+",
"stdout_lines": [
    "+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------------+",
    "| Property                          | Value                                    |",
    "+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------------+",
    "| QoS_support                       | True                                     |",
    "| allocated_capacity_gb             | 0                                        |",
    "| easytier_support                  | True                                     |",
    "| free_capacity_gb                  | 0.0                                      |",
    "| location_info                     | xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:pool2   |",
    "| max_over_subscription_ratio       | 20.0                                     |",
    "| multiattach                       | True                                     |",
    "| name                              | abc86#pool2                              |",
    "| pool_name                         | pool2                                    |",
    "| provisioned_capacity_gb           | 0.0                                      |",
    "| reserved_percentage               | 0                                        |",
    "| total_capacity_gb                 | 0.0                                      |",
    "| volume_backend_name               | abc86                                    |",
    "+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------------+",
    "+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------------+",
    "| Property                          | Value                                    |",
    "+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------------+",
    "| QoS_support                       | True                                     |",
    "| allocated_capacity_gb             | 950                                      |",
    "| easytier_support                  | True                                     |",
    "| free_capacity_gb                  | 750.0                                    |",
    "| location_info                     | xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:pool3   |",
    "| max_over_subscription_ratio       | 20.0                                     |",
    "| multiattach                       | True                                     |",
    "| name                              | abc86#pool3                              |",
    "| pool_name                         | pool3                                    |",
    "| provisioned_capacity_gb           | 650.0                                    |",
    "| reserved_percentage               | 0                                        |",
    "| total_capacity_gb                 | 1000.0                                   |",
    "| volume_backend_name               | abc86                                    |",
    "+-----------------------------------+------------------------------------------+",
```

I need to debug (pool_name), (free_capacity_gb) and (total_capacity_gb) of each pool from stdout.

Comment: You will get better help here if you include the "something" that is wrong with your code. What error does it produce? What output does it produce that you wish it didn't? Is that code snippet literally the only thing you have tried, as if ansible is going to parse those lines into a `dict` for you?

Comment: code updated..@Matthew L Daniel

Answer (score -1):

As I correctly observed, ansible does not auto-parse textual output from commands.

You will want [`regex_replace`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#regular-expression-filters) to extract the key-value pairs you care about, and then you can do some text ninjary to convert them *into* a `dict`, taking advantage of the fact that yaml is such a liberal syntax

```
- debug:
    msg: >-
     {{ 
      pools.stdout_lines
      | select("regex", '[|] Property | '+the_pattern)
      | map("regex_replace", '^[|] Property.*', '- ')
      | map("regex_replace", the_pattern, '  "\1": "\2"')
      | join(newline_char)
      | from_yaml }}
  vars:
    newline_char: "\n"
    the_pattern: '[|] (free_capacity_gb|pool_name|total_capacity_gb) [|] ([^ ]+)'
```

You'll need that `select` in there to discard non-matching lines, else the `regex_replace` won't *replace* anything and you'll end up with malformed YAML

Comment: You can chop off more and more of the trailing jinja pipeline to see what the shape of the lines looks like as it flows through the pipeline, leading to a `null` entry. I tested that snippet on your posted `stdout_lines` but, of course, if your actual `stdout_lines` differs, then you'll end up with a different outcome

Comment: A little more help Matthew, I could not work this out. My stdout_lines are same as I posted but still I get null values. Could you share, how you tested and what exact output of debug you get? @Matthew L Daniel